# How to extract the last row of a matrix in R with row name displayed?

Tags: r, matrix

I had a matrix called "FM" and I wanted to extract the last row of it. So I tried

```
FM[nrow(FM), ]
```

However it gave me the last row without the row name in the front (but the column name was displayed). How can I get the last row with the row name displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Use `drop = FALSE`

```
FM <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
dimnames(FM) <- list(letters[1:3], letters[1:3])

mat[nrow(mat), ]
#a b c 
#3 6 9 

mat[nrow(mat), , drop = FALSE]
#  a b c
#c 3 6 9
```

By default, the value of `drop` is `TRUE`. From `?Extract`

> drop - For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension

In the first case, R coerces it to a named integer vector which does not have rownames

```
class(mat[nrow(mat), ])
#[1] "integer"
```

if we use `drop = FALSE` it maintains the dimension and keep it as a matrix thus preserving rownames

```
class(mat[nrow(mat), , drop = FALSE])
#[1] "matrix"
```